Cannot destructure React context object
//App.tsx
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { defaultFormData } from "./components/Context";

const theme = createTheme({
    typography: {
        fontFamily: "Manrope, sans-serif",
    },
});

export const FormStateContext = createContext({});

function App() {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState(defaultFormData);

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <FormStateContext.Provider value={{ formData, setFormData }}>


//step.tsx

import { FormStateContext } from "../../App";
import { useContext } from "react";

export function step() {
    const {formData, setFormData} = useContext(FormStateContext);

Every time I try to destructure the object in any way I get the error which says that the attributes don't exist in the type {}.
Edit: sorry, i've forgotten to include the rest of the code, hope it'll help somehow, if anyone wants to view the entirety of this trash pile here's the github link

Can you show how FormStateContext is defined. The error is mostly because of typescript but to fix this we need more context into your code

If you pass {} as the initial context then TypeScript will infer the type as {}. You need to pass some default value, otherwise TypeScript is correct to point out the error.

i've done it but what value should i pass to the useState hook now? Also, in the value context provider prop for the context value now an error shows up that says "Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'formData' does not exist in type 'FormValues'.ts(2353)
index.d.ts(603, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps"
and sorry if can't comprehend the error description, i'm still a beginner

When you call createContext({}) without any type anotation, typescript cannot do anything but infer the type {} to the context value
What you want to do instead is to assign the type
type ContextValue = {formData: MyFormData, setFormData: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<MyFormData>>}

In order to do so you should create the context this way:
const Context = createContext<null | ContextValue>(null);

We allow null to avoid having to pass an actual default value. It comes handy with complex context. Don't worry we get rid of it later on
With this you still can't destructure since the context can be null
To go around that create a custom hook that throws if the context is nullish
const useMyContext = () => {
   const ctx = useContext(Context) 
   if(!ctx) throw new Error('context not found') 
   return ctx
} 

This way useMyContext always returns the type ContextValue
You can new destructure
const {formData, setFormData} = useMyContext() 


Check the default value that you are using as createContext parameter it shouldn't be null or undefined.
const SomeContext = createContext(defaultValue)


I'm just passing {}, shouldn't it be considered an empty object?
